# how to distinguish between a checkbox field and a group of radio buttons

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

When I retrieve a PDF field by name using pdfbox with

```
PDField field = acroForm.getField('my_field');
```

I can't determine whether that field is a single checkbox or a group of radio buttons from neither the type of `field` nor `field.getFieldType()`, because they are the same in both cases.

I could do this

```
boolean isCheckbox = field.getWidgets().size() == 1;
```

But this is not entirely reliable either, because a radio group *could* contain just one button.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` can be used to determine the type of the field. If it's a checkbox, the type will be `PDCheckbox`. If the field is a group of radio buttons the type should be `PDRadioCollection`. The code below will do the trick on PDFBox version 1.8.10. I appears that the class structure for AcroForms has changes on PDFBox 2.0.0.

```
if(field instanceof PDCheckbox){
    type="CheckBox";
}else if(field instanceof PDRadioCollection){
    type="Radio";
}
```

For version 2.0.0, according to the API documentation found [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDButton.html), `PDButton` is a superclass of `PDCheckbox` and `PDRadioButton`. This will change the code above, as we will be checking for `field instanceof PDCheckbox` and `field instanceof PDRadioButton`.

Note that there was also a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2617) related to this issue. It looks like the bug has since been fixed, so make sure the fix is in your release of PDFBox.

Comment: This is true in older versions of pdfbox, but since about version 1.8.10, both radio buttons and checkboxes have type `PDCheckbox`

Comment: That's a great point. It looks like there were indeed some changes in 2.0.0. Take a look at my updated answer, and let me know if this works for you, as I'm yet to test with 2.0.0. Also note the bug report I saw about this issue, mentioned in the bottom.

Comment: @Little Bobby Drop Tables, did my updated suggestion work for you? I made some updates that will work on PDFBox 2.0.0.